# calling an abstract GUI class from main method in java

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to view my GUI from the main class (as another class) but I keep getting errors. The GUI class compiles fine but the main class "cannot instantiate the type RecommenderGUI". Here is some of the code from the GUI class

```
public abstract class RecommenderGUI extends JFrame {

private static final Dimension MAX_BTN_DIM = new Dimension(100, 1);
protected static final int DESCDISPLAYLENGTH = 40;
protected final int FRAME_WIDTH = 456;
protected final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 683;
/**
 * Current user
 */
protected JLabel curUserLabel = new JLabel("Set current user id");
protected JTextField curUserTextField;
protected JButton curUserSetBtn = new JButton();
protected JLabel curUserStatusLabel;
/**
 * Add item
 */
protected JComboBox addItemList;
protected JComboBox addRatingList;
protected JButton addItemBtn;
/**
 * Get recommendations
 */
```

And here is my main method:

```
public class RecommenderRunner {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    RecommenderGUI gui = new RecommenderGUI();
     gui.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

It doesn't seem to be recognising my GUI class. Any help will be much appreciated. regards.

Comment: Your class is `abstract` and therefore can't be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the basics of the language before trying to create gui's. You can't instantiate it, because it is an abstract class.

This means it might (not necessary) contain abstract (non-implemented) methods.
You'll need to create a subclass in order to be able to instantiate it through that subclass (or an anonymous inner class).

But, most likely, you'll just need to remove the 'abstract' keyword from the class signature. I can't be fore sure, based on the little code you show, but it doesn't seem like the class is supposed to be abstract to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed the abstract and it works.